# TV and PC sharing USB external drive?

Tags: usb, tv

I would like to know whether it is possible to connect a LED TV and computer to a USB external drive at the same time?

Ultimately it would mean nothing needs to be unplugged and I can enjoy media off the drive on my TV without carrying it back and forward.

Any advice would be appreciated?

Comment: What model TV is it?

Comment: Do you intend to plug both the TV and computer into the USB external drive, or share it using software?

Comment: thanks for the reply. It is a LD 42" LED TV LE5300 and yes, I would like to plug both the TV and computer into the USB external drive. That would be first prize. It would basically mean that I dont have to move the USB drive around from pc to tv.

Answer (score 0):

Not without an active switch in the way. USB is a two-way system, so it should be connect to one device at a time... This means you would need something to actively "disconnect" from one source and "connect" to the other source without physically unplugging it.

I have seen some niche items in the past that would do this, but I have not tested any